How to modularize this Shiny application?
I am trying to modularize an existing single file application. I tried to check existing answers in this topic, but still not able to get my demo code to work. I guess I am close to the working solution but there is something I still missing or misused.
library(shiny)

uiModule <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = "actBtn1", label = "do"),
    actionButton(inputId = "actBtn2", label = "do2")
  )
}

srvModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns

  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, ns(input$actBtn1) , {
    message("clicked 111")
  })
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, ns(input$actBtn2) , {
    message("clicked 222")
  })  
}

serverMain <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(menuItem(
      "Menu item",
      tabName = "dashboard",
      icon = icon("calendar")
    ))
  })
  moduleServer( id = "myMod", module = srvModule, session = session)
}


uiMain <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Mysidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "mytabs", sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(
    tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content")
  )), uiModule("myModuleUI"))
)

shinyApp(uiMain, serverMain)


What can I try next?

Tip: if you generate a username by randomly bashing the keyboard, it shall be thought that you don't intend to be around for long, and that you want free labour without wanting to be a member of the community. If you can, set a decent username, and consider contributing as well.

It looks like you've also asked for "logic-template based on the [above] if it is a dynamic UI", but it would be better if you make an honest attempt at that first. If you have any issues with that, ask a new question.

Thus, if the existing answer worked for you, you can "accept" it, by clicking the tick/check mark.

There are a few changes to your approach that I would recommend

in uiModule, you need to wrap the inputId values with ns(). For example

actionButton(inputID = ns("actBtn1"), ...)


the signature for srvModule should be function(id), and the function should return the result of a moduleServer() function.

Within that moduleServer() function you do not need to wrap your references to inputs with ns().  For example, instead of


observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, ns(input$actBtn1), ...)

you need to use
observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, input$actBtn1, ...)


The id value that you pass to srvModule() and to uiModule() needs to be the same value (for example "myMod").

Here is a full working example:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

uiModule <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = ns("actBtn1"), label = "do"),
    actionButton(inputId = ns("actBtn2"), label = "do2")
  )
}

srvModule <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, input$actBtn1 , {
      message("clicked 111")
    })
    observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, input$actBtn2 , {
      message("clicked 222")
    })  
  })
}

serverMain <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(menuItem(
      "Menu item",
      tabName = "dashboard",
      icon = icon("calendar")
    ))
  })
  srvModule(id = "myMod")
}


uiMain <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Mysidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "mytabs", sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(
    tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content")
  )), uiModule(id = "myMod"))
)

shinyApp(uiMain, serverMain)


&@&!%...... many thanks, I feel so lame now

Could you PLS also provide a logic-template based on the aboves if it is a dynamic UI (i.e. uiModule consists only uiOutput("id") whereas the ui components are rendered on the serverModule side) ? Thanks in advance!

I have suggested that the OP try something with their latest request, rather than being spoonfed work continuously. It is good practice for engineers!
